# Are there any good parsing libraries for .Net?

Tags: .net, parsing

I'm looking for something simple to use where the grammar is easy to define.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Although I've never used it before, [ANTLR](http://www.antlr.org/) has C# runtime.

Answer (score 4):

If you use F#, check out [FParsec](http://www.quanttec.com/fparsec/).

Answer (score 2):

Just found out about [Irony](http://www.codeplex.com/irony). Used for writing [DSL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain-specific_language).
Thought I would add it to the list.

Answer (score 1):

System.Text.RegularExpressions?

Comment: That's a pretty brave answer.  There's some real Zealots who will only condone real parsers, and not using things like Regex for parsing code.

Comment: I'll take that as a valid answer since I didn't define my needs and there are cases where regular expressions are sufficient to define simple DSL.

Answer (score 1):

Give a look to [Coco/R for C#](http://www.ssw.uni-linz.ac.at/Research/Projects/Coco/#CS).